# Equivalent Command for "members" in RHEL

Tags: linux, rhel

I have requirement to check members of the group "wheel" periodically.

I see that 'members wheel' is expected to display the members of that group. However when i tried, it says command not found. I see no entries in the man page as well.

I am using RHEL - Linux Version 3.10 (Red Hat 4.8.5)

I know we can use awk and cat in combination to get these details from "/etc/group" file

But is there a straight forward or a better approach?

Comment: "*I see that 'members wheel' is expected to display the members of that group*" - where do you see that?

Comment: I don't have RHEL to test it, but does `perl -wE 'say((getgrnam $ARGV[0])[3])' wheel` do anything useful?

Comment: @melpomene

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-all-members-of-a-group/

Comment: Well, that page also says "*__Warning__: `members` command is not installed on most distros.*" and that you may have to install it explicitly first.

Comment: @melpomene ... silly me :) thank you... I will get it installed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an [answered question from Linux admin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241215/how-can-i-find-out-which-users-are-in-a-group-within-linux).

In short the answer is:

> I prefer to use the getent command ...
>
> Since getent uses the same name service as the system, getent will show all information, including that gained from network information sources such as LDAP.
>
> So for a group, you should use the following ...
>
> ```
> getent group name_of_group
> ```
>
> where name_of_group is replaced with the group you want to look up.
> Note that this only returns supplementary group memberships, it
> doesn't include the users who have this group as their primary group.
>
> There are a whole lot of other lookups that you can do ... passwd
> being another useful one, which you'll need to list primary groups.